# How can I reset an AmChart?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to figure out the best way to dynamically clear/reset an AmChart. I have the following chart:

```
amchart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
```

I have tried simply re-initializing it to clear it for rewriting but it fails with the chart going a solid gray. The best luck I have had has been calling specific functions and resetting specific attributes such as follows:

```
amchart.titles = [];
amchart.clearLabels();
```

I have used the API as a guide: http://docs.amcharts.com/2/javascriptcharts/AmChart

When the graph is rewritten it looks largely ok but some elements such as the side label are off. I have noticed this only when a legend is present. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

To clear a chart with multiple data series, keep removing the first series until there are none left.

```
     while(chart.series.length) {
         chart.series.removeIndex(0).dispose();
     }
```

The link posted by @Laurent is useful: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/dynamically-adding-and-removing-series/

Note that the key (or id) of the old series is retained in the chart's map. So you can't create a new series with the same id. In that case, you may prefer to just empty the series' data [].

```
    const series = chart.series.getIndex(indexToRemove);
    series.data = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, Id consider trying:

```
amchart.validateNow();
// or
amchart.validateData();
```

After setting the properties and/or data provider on your chart.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the series by using

```
chart.series.removeIndex(0);
```

Check here : https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/dynamically-adding-and-removing-series/

Answer (score -1):

To clear a chart simply use chart.clear();

Comment: chart.clear() is not a function